# How to get elements from List<> using Linq and Dictionary in query C#?

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

There is the model:

```
public class Word
{
    public Dictionary<string, string> Langs { get; set; }
}
```

There is a list of languages to use:

```
    // I need to use these 2 langs only
    List<string> langsToUse = new List<string> { "en", "pl" };
```

The List of words contains not needed langs or not valid langs:

```
List<Word> wordsList = new List<Word> {
new Word {
    Langs = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"en", "Dog"},
        {"pl", "Pies"},
        {"ge", "Hund"},
        //... and so on
    }},
new Word {
    Langs = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"en", "Kat"},
        {"pl", ""},
        {"ge", ""}
        //... and so on
    }},
new Word {
    Langs = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        {"en", "Car"},
        {"pl", ""},
        {"ge", ""}
        //... and so on
    }},
};
```

The plain way to walidate it is:

```
// And value shouldn't be ""
var validWords = wordsList.Where(p => p.Langs["en"] != "" &&
                                      p.Langs["pl"] != "");
```

I don't want to type "en", "pl" keys manually each time so I need to  automatize it somehow, somehow like this:

```
// use foreach for validate words
List<Word> validWords_2 = new List<Word>();

foreach(Word word in wordsList)
{
    bool isWordValid = true;

    foreach(string lang in langsToUse)
    {
        if(word.Langs[lang] == ""){
            isWordValid = false;
        }
    }

    if(isWordValid) {
        validWords_2.Add(word);
    }
}
```

But I think this automatization may be done simpler in case there is some way to do it with using Linq and Dictionary somehow.

Comment: You have told us what you actually want to do, just some code that doesn't make sense, Please state your expected results, with some meaningful input

Comment: updated description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your validation code using LINQ like this:

```
var validWords = wordsList
    .Where(word => langsToUse.All(lang => word.Langs[lang] != ""))
    .ToList();
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/qqLxzd

The above assumes that all the `Langs` dictionaries will contain a key for each language in `langsToUse`.  If that is not the case you should use `TryGetValue`:

```
var validWords = wordsList
    .Where(word => langsToUse.All(
                   lang => word.Langs.TryGetValue(lang, out string w) && w != ""))
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can try to use linq `join`

```
List<string> keyList = new List<string> { "key_01", "key_02" };
var dictionary_name = new Dictionary<string, string>()
            {
                {"key_01", "val_01"},
                {"key_02", "val_02"}
            };
var results = from i in keyList
            join k in dictionary_name on i equals k.Key
            select i;
```

Or only use `Contains` method.

```
dictionary_name.Where(x => keyList.Contains(x.Key));
```